# Error when logging in using SPLoginViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm building an iOS application which implements the Spotify API (and am using CocoaLibSpotify). I'm using SPLoginViewController for login so the user can perform an SPSearch. The SPLoginViewController presents itself correctly and the SPSession is active; however, whenever I enter in (valid) credentials for login, the app crashes and the console shows:

> +[NSURL urlEncodedStringForString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x274cd14

I set an exception breakpoint. Here's the block where the error occurs, with the specific line put in ** (towards bottom of block):

```
-(void)loadUserData {

    SPAssertOnLibSpotifyThread();

    BOOL userLoaded = sp_user_is_loaded(self.user);
    NSURL *url = nil;
    NSString *canonicalString = nil;
    NSString *displayString = nil;

    if (userLoaded) {

        sp_link *link = sp_link_create_from_user(self.user);
        if (link != NULL) {
            **url = [NSURL urlWithSpotifyLink:link];**
            sp_link_release(link);
        }
```

Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: On what line does this crash occur?  Showing some code would be helpful.

Comment: @JonathanArbogast edited to add chunk of code where error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the "Building - iOS" section of the [readme](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify) file, make sure you add `-ObjC` to the "Other Linker Flags" build setting of your project.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked, but I'm sure you already knew that!